# Replace function calls using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, sed

I have this function that works like this

```
Add(1,2);
Add(3,4);
```

And need to replace with this

```
Add({num1 : 1, num2 : 2});
Add({num1 : 3, num2 : 4});
```

This happens in hundreds of places across multiple files so I want to write a script that can do this for me.

Using regex I can find the places where this happens

```
/Add\(.*\);/
```

But I'm not sure how to replace the inside of the function call with what I need.

I'm not sure also what the best langauge to use to write the script. I was going to use JavasScript to write it in node but would use Bash with sed if there is an easy solution there.

Comment: Instead of changing all calls, you could also change the method so it understands either of the invocations. In JavaScript you can check for the second parameter being `undefined` and then extract the values from the object provided as first parameter. Most other languages understand default values or proper method overloading.

Comment: For my case it is important that all the calls would need to changed so it just accepts one object.

Comment: What if there is `Add(1,2,3,4,5);`?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/62xbtzpx/1/ that should work with `numberXXX` and with any number of numeric arguments inside the `Add(...)`.

Comment: If my fiddle is what you need, please let me know so that I could re-post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with:

```
perl -i -pe 's/Add\((\d+),(\d+)\)/Add({num1 : $1, num2 : $2})/' filename
```

Regarding your regular expression, it's not complete, and `/Add\((\d+),(\d+)\)/` will take care of catching the instruction and capturing the first and second numbers into `$1` and `$2`, respectively.

The flags work as follows:

- `-i` does in-place edit (this will rewrite your file; if you're not comfortable with that either remove the flag to look at the output or use `-i.bak` to create a backup of your file
- `-p` parses each line and prints it in the end
- `-e` (from "eval") is what allows you to run a one-liner instead of a script

Comment: I've never used perl before. How would I run this on a specific file?

Comment: As long as you have Perl installed you can just type the line above in the command line; use the `-i.bak` version so you get to keep a backup copy of your original file.

Comment: What if there is `Add(1,2,3,4,5);`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew then you'd need either several regular expressions or a single regular expression ( `Add\((\d+,\d+(?:,\d+)*)\)` ) and you'd need to parse those differently.

Comment: Lastly sometimes the number inside is a variable eg Add(number1, number2) How do I deal with this?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38373079/3832970) that deals with all your requirements. Unless you need to also support floats :)

Comment: If the number is inside a variable you can alter the `\d+` to something like `\w+` (that will also catch things like "1number", which presumably wouldn't be a variable, but I think you're safe

Answer (score 2):

You could use replace with an appropriate string.

```js
var regex= /(Add\()(\d+),(\d+)(\))/g,
    replace = '$1{num1: $2, num2: $3}$4'

console.log('Add(3,4);'.replace(regex, replace));
```

Comment: What if there is `Add(1,2,3,4,5);`?

Comment: the it need another regex with another replacement string. the op didn't mention it.

Comment: I have provided a [generic JS solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38373079/3832970) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sed method

```
sed 's/\([^(]\+.\)\([^,]\+.\)\([^)]\+\)\(.*\)/\1{num1 : \2,num2 : \3}\4/g' FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
sed -i 's/Add(\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\))/Add({num1 : \1, num2 : \2})/' file
```

The `-i` option is for editing the file *in place*.